# Post on wall - image dimensions limit?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-wall

I'm posting images ot wall. Tried 200x200. Result on wall is: 96x96.
But I saw images on other posts with bigger dimmensions.
Where are the limitations described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you share a URL, the maximal size for a linked image is 90x90.

Answer (score 2):

Images with dimensions bigger than 96x96 in `feed` is photos that was uploaded by user, and not posts created by application.

Documentation is a bit poor on that but there is no hard limit for image dimensions but the image will be displayed in different sizes across different views (this was stated in comments to several bugs, and I cannot find the source right now).

This means that in feed image will be displayed one size and the Timeline may display bigger version if available, and some other views may use other dimensions as well. One rule exists (which is stated about images across different documentation pages: [Share](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/), [OpenGraph Protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/), [Feed Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/))

> The image must be at least 50px by 50px and have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1